# What's wrong with these pointer initialization

Tags: c++

```
char * a=0;
int * b=0;
cout<<a<<a+1;
cout<<b<<b+1;
```

what's wrong with it

Comment: Care to be more specific? What do you think is wrong and what results are you expecting?

Answer (score 8):

The initializations are fine. Doing pointer arithmetic on NULL pointers is wrong.

Also, `cout << (const char*)` assumes the operand is a valid C-style string, not a NULL pointer. If you want to print the address of the string, not the string itself, you'll need to cast it because otherwise char pointers receive special treatment.

```
char* a = 0;
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning null (0) to the value of your pointers, which means they do not reference a valid memory location.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing wrong with it.

maybe something's wrong with what you expect of this code.